# Bash if block syntax

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I'm having a syntax error with this if block and can't I haven't been able to correct it

```
if [[ $X >= 100] || [$Y >= 100 ]]
then
   echo "..."
fi
```

I've rewrote this, but haven't had any luck on finding the correct syntax. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax error, you should try :

```
if ((X >= 100 || Y >= 100 ))
then
   echo "..."
fi
```

### NOTE

- with this syntax, no need to remember `-ge` and such. This is just like arithmetic
- `((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for `let`, if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is this :

```
if [[ $X -ge 100 || $Y -ge 100 ]];
then
   echo "..."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` is fine. Your `[[` command is screwed up.

```
if [[ $X -ge 100 || $Y -ge 100 ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to nest `[...]` expressions, which is not something you can do in `bash`. The `[[ ... ]]` expression is an entirely separate construct available in `bash`. I won't bother posting a correct expression, as the other answers have that well covered.